# Menu with select color

Tags: android, menu, colors, android-menu

How can I create such a thing?

[image]

I have tried with context menu, popup menu but  I'm not be able to  make a menu like this.

I am a beginner, I hope you manage to understand me

**EDIT**

I have created the Custom Dialog but when I go to manage the touch of a button I get this error

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Custom Dialog XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:background="@drawable/curve_shap"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_dia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Seleziona un colore"
    android:textColor="#ff383838"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/md_grey_50"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/indigo"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_indigo"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orange"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_orange"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_red"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/light_green"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_light_green"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cyan"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_cyano"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did u tried custom dialog? Post your layout xml file...

Comment: yes, you can do by custom dialog..

Comment: @RishadAppat  look first post

Comment: @Saveen look first post

Comment: First post your layout xml file for the menu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi Do something like that..hope this is helpfull for you

```
Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(activity);
    // dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.xmldesignfordialog);
    // dialog2.getWindow().getDecorView().setTop(20);
    // dialog2.getWindow().getDecorView().setLeft(100);
    dialog2.setTitle("Response");

    final TextView tvreply_first = (TextView) dialog2
            .findViewById(R.id.tvreply_first);
    final TextView tvreply_second = (TextView) dialog2
            .findViewById(R.id.tvreply_second);
    final TextView tvreply_third = (TextView) dialog2
            .findViewById(R.id.tvreply_third);
    tvreply_first.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         // Do Any click here

            dialog2.dismiss();

        }
    });
    tvreply_second
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    dialog2.dismiss();
                }
            });
    tvreply_third.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog2.dismiss();

        }
    });

    dialog2.show();
```